# Bar chart in pgfplots offset with missing data

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I would like to create a bar plot with pgfplots where I add multiple data with successive `addplot+` commands, such as:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  height=4.5cm,
  xbar=0pt,
  bar width=7pt,
]
\addplot+ coordinates { (10,1) (5,2) (30,3) };
\addplot+ coordinates {  (8,1)       (14,3) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

As shown on the picture, at y = 2, there is only data from the first `addplot`, not from the second. In such cases, pgfplots seems to allocate space for data from additional bars, leading the single bar to look "offset". Is there a way to make pgfplots allocate no space for bars for which no data is given, additionally leading the single bar at y = 2 to be centered vertically?

Answer (score 1):

Is it an option to single out these points in a separate `\addplot` like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xbar=0pt,
]
\addplot+[bar shift=0pt, forget plot] coordinates { (5,2) };
\addplot coordinates { (10,1) (30,3) };
\addplot coordinates { (8,1) (14,3) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Barplot]